# Image and Kernel of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ where B is an $r \times r$ matrix and rank(B) $= r \le$ min{n, m}.

Find the ker(L) and image(L).

I honestly don't know where to start. My teacher never showed us how to do these type of problems. I am able to find the image and kernel of a regular matrix. but I am confused when it comes to the block matrix.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you think of a way to relate the image (perhaps via column space) of $B$ to that of $A$? The kernel can be found in a similar fashion

Comment: Since B is a square matrix, the kernel is 0 and the image is spanned by the columns of B.

Comment: Only one of those statements is true, but do you see how you can extend (literally) those facts to this case?

Comment: No, not really. It's not so obvious to me.

Comment: Think about what it means for $B$ to have maximal rank. Maybe it helps to think about reduced row echelon forms. Knowing that $B$ has maximal rank, what is the reduced row echelon form of $B$? This gives you a reduced row echelon form of $A$ for free. Infer what the image and kernel of $A$ are.

Comment: image is the span of the standard basis vectors and kernel is 0? I think. I'm not sure.

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$? Do they have something to do with $A$?

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm pretty sure $A$ is meant to be $m \times n$, as usual

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We can figure out everything we need to by bringing everything back to definitions, and noticing that a vector $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ can be broken into the "block-vector" $(x',x'')$ with $x' \in \Bbb R^r$ and $x'' \in \Bbb R^{n-r}$, so that
$$
Ax = \pmatrix{B&0\\0&0}\pmatrix{x'\\x''} = \pmatrix{Bx'\\0}
$$